# creating a menu for navigation in file

Tags: navigation

while coding in vim I use often special comment to denote
section of the file. For example in C it is

```
//;; some title 1
//;; some title 2
```

I have also configured a shortcut to print with a global command (g/.../p)
all such entries in the file.

The output print looks like

```
16 //;; some title 1
32 //;; some title 2
```

then I just type `:` and the line number to jump directly to the line.

Although I am quite satisfied with it, it would be much faster If i could
navigate in this list like a mini buffer and then select the entry.

As I use fzf in vim I was thinking about creating a vim list to input to fzf. However the idea got much harder to implement as expected.

Is there some easier way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a pretty good use-case for the location list, so here is one "vanilla vim" solution:

```
:lvimgrep '\V//;;' % | lopen
```

You can make a mapping or a command around this.

Breakdown: `lvimgrep` loads the location list with lines matching `//;;` (we use `\V` to make it easier to enter this pattern), from the current file (`%`).  Then we open the location list using `lopen`.

You can also use `:lnext` and `:lprev` (among other commands) to navigate between positoins.